# Change Gimp python interpreter path

Tags: python, python-2.7, gimp, pythonpath

I am developing a custom GIMP plugin on Mac OS X. For programming reasons, I need to use some python modules that I have installed in system's default python environment (such as OpenCV, MoviePy, and some others), but I am unable to import them on the Python-Fu console because it uses the GIMP's app built-in python environment. My question is. Is there a way to tell GIMP to use another python interpreter? I've searched on GIMP preferences but I haven't found anything such as Python-Fu path or something similar.

GIMP's Python interpreter is found here on my system: `/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/python`

The interpreter that I want GIMP to use is found here on my system: `/usr/bin/python`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See `/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/interpreters/pygimp.interp` (or wherever this is in your Gimp installation directory). You can tweak this to use another Python instance (but it still has to be 2.7.x). On the other hand Gimp's own Python interpreter is the standard cpython, you can use it directly in the command line and can likely tweak `pip`  to install modules for it (or add the modules installed on the other instance to it).

Comment: If I can use pip to install modules, perfect, but how can I tell the command line to install those modules into GIMP's Python directory? I am comfortable with the command line, but these things quite exceed my knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure PIP installs things for the python runtime that is used to run it, so it would be  a mere matter of changing the path temporarily (but you would have to first install PIP for Gimp's python runtime)

Comment: Thing is I can't run GIMP's python within the terminal

Comment: And I don't have a pygimp.interp file in my GIMP installation

Comment: You have something like `lib/gimp/2.0/` and no `lib/gimp/2.0/interpreters` ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "can't run"?

Comment: Finally I managed to run it by using Windows and not macOS. @xenoid I have `lib/gimp/2.0/interpreters` directory, but there's no `pygimp.interp` file inside

Comment: For others who had trouble finding `pygimp.interp` on MacOS, I was able to locate it  at `/Applications/GIMP-2.10.app/Contents/Resources/lib/gimp/2.0/interpreters/pygimp.interp`